# Sort formating date in DataTable Angular

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I have my API and I get it using `HTTP GET` I cast my info with my model **Alert** taht contains a `Date` type **timestamp** if I run the DataTable with a Date type I can sort the column, but the problem here is the format I'm getting the following format

> Mon Sep 03 2018 01:56:36 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time (Mexico))

When I try to have a formated date like `09/03/2018 01:56:36` If I run the datatable with this format the sort doesn't work because it sort as **String** and not as **Date**

My question is: How can I have a Date Type formated as `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss` ??

Note: I'm using [ng2-smart-table](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table) as Datable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as per [documentation](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation)

You can declare pre-render function `valuePrepareFunction` for any field.
So, you can import DatePipe directly:

`import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';`

and return `new DatePipe('en-US').transform(date, 'your-format-here');` inside `valuePrepareFunction` declaration

Comment: Thanks you you answer  It helps me a lot.

Comment: is this working? I have this format date `"2019-10-01T08:52:45.563"` and and format the date using DatePipe and return it inside the `valuePrepareFunction` but the sorting still not working.

Comment: @AbelValdez is this correct?
`

        lastLoginTime: {
          title: 'Last Login',
          width: '15%',
          filter: false,
          valuePrepareFunction: (lastLoginTime: any) => {
            return lastLoginTime?
              new DatePipe('en-US').transform(lastLoginTime, 'M/d/yyyy') :
              new DatePipe('en-US').transform('2019-12-03T08:52:45.563', 'd/M/yyyy');
          }
        },
`

Answer (score 2):

Do not format the date. Let it as timestamp and use the `valuePrepareFunction` to transform the timestamp in your formatted date.

If it is already what you are doing so I can see that the sort uses the prepared value and not the original one.

In this case, use the `compareFunction` to transform the date in timestamp again when sorting.

https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation